# Bootstrap 3 - Line label up with form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get this label to line up horizontally with the text input and button, but am not succeeding. The label is instead being stacked on top of the text input. Here is the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Jz9nkuctxr).

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <label for="id-message">ResidentBiscuit</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="chat-message" placeholder="Enter your message...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Send</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a form with form-inline class?

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="chat-message">ResidentBiscuit</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="chat-message" placeholder="Enter your message...">
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Send</button>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/MEub8RYgwj

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that. I need the text input to fill up as much space as it can though.